# Trying to use lsmeans without package "lmerTest"

Tags: comparison, lme4, mixed-models, lsmeans, lmertest

I am running the following mixed model using the package *lme4*:

```
moms.rest.lmer <- lmer(rest ~ habitat + (1|year) + (1|ID))
```

where rest is a numeric value, and habitat is a factor variable with 3 levels. I am trying to get pairwise comparisons of the 3 habitat levels using lsmeans from the package *lsmeans*:

```
moms.rest.lsm <- lsmeans(moms.rest.lmer, pairwise ~ habitat, adjust="Tukey")
```

I used this method for over a year with no problems, but I need to rerun the model and now suddenly I am hit with this error:

```
    Loading required namespace: lmerTest
    Failed with error:  ‘there is no package called ‘lmerTest’’
    Install package 'lmerTest' to obtain Satterthwaite degrees of freedom
```

I read that the package *lmerTest* has it's own version of lsmeans (lsmeansLT) but I don't want to use the *lmerTest* package as it seems it doesn't do pairwise comparisons. How do I get my old code to work using *lsmeans*?

Comment: Add `lmer.df = "k"` to the `lsmeans` call. Or specify the same in `lsm.options` to restore the previous default. See `? models` for more information.

Comment: Or you can just install lmerTest, and then it will be used to get the degrees of freedom – but nothing else.

Comment: Using lmer.df = "k" did the trick, thanks so much.

Comment: Great. But I still recommend just installing **lmerTest**. I changed the default to Satterthwaite, which uses that package's routines, because it requires less computation and some users had had extremely slow response (tens of minutes or even hours) with the K-R method implemented in **pbkrtest**. You will still get all the same kinds of results from the **lsmeans** package. It doesn't give you `lsmeansLT` results instead. (BTW, I think **lmerTest** provides a `difflsmeans` function if you want to do pairwise comparisons with its interface).

Comment: OK thanks for that. Your advice and expertise are greatly appreciated!